# How to use bulk_write to quickly update MongoDB Collection?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to update my whole DB from a Pandas DF but looping takes ages and I´m not familiar enough with pymongo to get it running. This is what I tried but I keep getting this error when trying to update the DB after changing the data in Pandas. What am I doing wrong?

```
'errmsg': "E11000 duplicate key error collection"
df = df.to_dict('records')

collection.bulk_write([ReplaceOne(
                                 record,
                                 record,
                                 upsert=True
                                 )
                                for record in df
                       ], ordered=False)
```

Comment: Before you reassign `df`, what is `df.columns`?

Comment: my df basically looks like this:
"_id","TITLE","DATE","SALES"
I select all rows by a certain date:
df = df.loc[df[search_column].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)]

Comment: What indexes do you have on the collection?  Which indexes have the `unique` property?

Comment: I assumed that _id is automatically the UID. Is the problem that I haven´t explicitly assigned the unique property here?

Comment: There is always a unique index for `"_id" `. Duplicate values for any field with a unique index are not allowed. Does the collection have any other indexes?

Comment: Not that I know of. How do I check this? 
But you agree that my code is correct?

Comment: You can check the collection indexes with [`list_indexes`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.list_indexes) and/or [`index_information`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.index_information).  You can check `df` for any non-unique values.

Comment: SON([('v', 2), ('key', SON([('_id', 1)])), ('name', '_id_')])
This is the output which I don´t understand unfortunately.

Comment: Well, if that's the full output of `list_indexes`, then there is only one index.  Are you sure you want to use the entire doc as the `ReplaceOne` filter?  If `"_id"` matches, but the rest doesn't, then the filter won't match, and then an `upsert` will be attempted.  If there is already a doc with the same `"_id"` value, wouldn't that explain the error?

Comment: You may be right and it was nonsense so I´ve tried something different now. First I filter my df by date and turn it into a dict:
`date_selected = df.loc[df[search_column].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)]
date_selected = date_selected.to_dict('records')`

Then I use update_many:
`collection.update_many(date_selected,date_selected,upsert=True)`

Result:
`TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping`

Why does this result in a type error when it should be a dict?

Comment: I have none of your data to validate.  You'll need to do that yourself.  However, I'm confident your original problem was trying to `"upsert"` a document where the `"_id"` value already existed in the collection.  `"_id"` always has a `unique` index so an error is generated if an insert is attempted with the same value.